# Variance of power of normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a normal random variable $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I know that $$E[X^k]=\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n \choose 2m}(2m-1)!!\sigma^{2m}\mu^{n-2m}.$$

Is there a similar formula for $Var(X^k)$?

Comment: Could it be you used `n` instead of `k` inside the $\sum$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to work it out from the given formula, together with:

$$Var[Z]=E[Z^2]-E[Z]^2.$$

Comment: For completeness: You can find the moments $E[X^n]$ for different n here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments